# Ajax multiple array not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

When I select values from **two different select** I get an error *tmp is null*

```
<form method="post" id="filterform">
       <select multiple name="category[]" id="category" class="select">
           <option value="10">Men Foreigner</option>
           <option value="11">Women Foreigner</option>
        </select>

        <select multiple name="hair[]" id="hair" class="select">
           <option value="Black">Black</option>
           <option value="Blond">Blond</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

jQuery part

```
   $("select.select").change( function() {
        var Thedata = $("#filterform").serialize();
            console.log(Thedata);

        $.ajax({
            data: Thedata,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'autocomplete.php?cat=filtermodelscall',
            })
            .done(function( html ) {
                $("tbody").html( html );
            });
    });
```

Log shows `Thedata` values which is *category%5B%5D=10&hair%5B%5D=Black*
I have no idea where come from this error. Also, when I select values from a single select, it is working.
Thank you for your help

Comment: it comes from []   category[]  why you don't use just name="category"

Comment: Because it is a multiple select. if name="category[]" is not an array and that I select multiple option in the same select, I am not able to retrieve all values in ajax

Comment: Where is "error tmp is null" error coming from in that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation.

When a text convert to encoded URL:

`[` convert to *%5B*

`]` convert to *%5D*

You need to decode encoded url using [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) JS function like this:

```js
$("select.select").change( function() {
    var Thedata = $("#filterform").serialize();
    console.log(decodeURIComponent(Thedata));          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="filterform">
       <select multiple name="category[]" id="category" class="select">
           <option value="10">Men Foreigner</option>
           <option value="11">Women Foreigner</option>
        </select>

        <select multiple name="hair[]" id="hair" class="select">
           <option value="Black">Black</option>
           <option value="Blond">Blond</option>
        </select>
</form>
```